# WHM/Cpanel email spam

Tags: linux

I have just been notified of spam emails coming from my server, luckily i limit the amount of emails sent per account to 50 per hour, I have taken a screenshot on my mail reports, all of these email addresses are non existent how has this happened and how can I prevent it?

[image]

I have changed the Cpanel password.

Comment: Beside the "compromised server" situation, any question regarding CPanel and similar products are [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Can you please post the output of grep 1a46Z7-0006ku-8J /var/log/exim/main.log? Or, if the log rotated, can you run zgrep that email ID in the gzipped log?